# How can I sort value by std::nth_element function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, std

Actually, I am trying to get values that are partially sorted. I used `std::nth_element` function, here, but it is not giving me the expected result.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void print(vector<int>data)
{
     for(int i:data)
         cout<<i<<" ";
}

int main()
{
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r+", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w+", stdout);
#endif
    vector<int> v({5,7,4,2,8,6,1,9,0,3});
    auto middle=v.begin()+v.size()/2;
    nth_element(v.begin(), middle ,v.end(), greater<int>());
    print(v);
}
```

expected result is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 1 2 0 3
```

but I am getting this

```
6 7 9 8 5 4 1 2 0 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's read the description of the algorithm<sup>1</sup>, emphasis mine:

> ```
> template< class RandomIt >                        // (1)
> void nth_element( RandomIt first, RandomIt nth, RandomIt last );   
>  
> template< class RandomIt, class Compare >         // (3)
> void nth_element( RandomIt first, RandomIt nth, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
> ```
>
> `nth_element` is a partial sorting algorithm that rearranges elements in [first, last) such that:
>
> - The element pointed at by nth is changed to whatever element would occur in that position if [first, last) were sorted.
> - All of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element.
>
> More formally, `nth_element` partially sorts the range [first, last) in ascending order so that the condition `!(*j < *i)` (for (1-2), or `comp(*j, *i) == false` for (3-4)) is met for **any `i` in the range `[first, nth)` and for any `j` in the range `[nth, last)`**. The element placed in the nth position is exactly the element that would occur in this position if the range was fully sorted.

Note that it *doesn't* say that the range `[first, nth)` will be sorted, nor will be the range `[nth, last)`, it only guarantees the position of the nth element. You can think of it as a partition algorithm.

If you want a complete order using only this function, you need to apply it multiple times, either recursively or in a loop.

---

<sup>1) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element</sup>